# Node script doesn't ever end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the node script below to basically copy the contents of some files and insert them to mongo.

The script never seems to end and even though all the data gets inserted successfully, I always have to do Ctrl+C to kill it.

Is there something i'm supposed to use in node.js to end a script?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
var dir = './seeds';
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Show connection error if there is one
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Database Connection Error:'));

// If we successfully connected to mongo
db.once('open', function callback() {

    var fs = require('fs'); // Used to get all the files in a directory

    // Read all the files in the folder
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {

        // Log the error if something went wrong
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error: '+err);
        }

        // For every file in the list
        list.forEach(function(file) {

            // Set the filename without the extension to the variable collection_name
            var collection_name = file.split(".")[0];
            var parsedJSON = require(dir + '/' + file);

            for(var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) {

                // Counts the number of records in the collection
                db.collection('cohort').count(function(err, count) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });

                db.collection(collection_name).insert(parsedJSON[i], function(err, records) {

                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    console.log(records[0]);
                    console.log("Record added as "+records[0]);

                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You might need to close the `db` connection.  As far as `node.js` can tell, that remains a possible source of events as long as it is open.

Comment: The answer is correct and the comments are correct. You basically need to understand you are running under an "event loop" and the consequence of that is that when you open event handlers "like you have" (even if you did not know you did) then the loop will wait for events. Close the handlers or explicitly "end the loop"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When everything is done, call `mongoose.disconnect()`. As @AaronDufour correctly points out, node will not exit while event handler callbacks are registered because it doesn't know that no more events are expected, like the connection emitting a 'close' or 'error' event, for example.

Answer (score 9):

you can call `process.exit();` to exit

Comment: But make sure all synchronous requests were completely handled.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me inside ECS containers.