# Winston Logger not terminating when function is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I testing the logging library Winston for Node.js.
I use VS Code as an IDE.

When using the normal function to store the logs into a file or print the logs into the debug console, everything works as exptected.
To File:
[image]

To Debug Console:
[image]

When trying to push the logs to a MongoDB the logs will be transfered as expected but the tool is not terminating. I always have to stop the process excution manually. What is the issue here?

[image]

[image]

It is like the debugger is not disconnecting properly as the end is missing like at the other transporter options:

"Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..."

This is my code (I got it from a youtube tutorial, but apparently it is working smooth on the side of the guy providing the tutorial):

> prod-logger.js

```
const { format, createLogger, transports } = require('winston');
const { timestamp, combine, colorize, errors, json } = format;
require('winston-mongodb');
require('dotenv').config()

const db_name = process.env.MONGODBNAME

function buildProdLogger(){
    return createLogger({
        format: combine(
            timestamp(),
            errors({stack: true}),
            json(),
        ),
        defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
        /* transports: [new transports.File({
            filename: './logs/logs.log'})], */
        /* transports: [new transports.Console({
        filename: './logs/logs.log'})], */
            transports: new transports.MongoDB({
                leve:'error',
                db: db_name,
                options: { useUnifiedTopology: true },
                collection: 'collection1'
            })
      });
}

module.exports = buildProdLogger;
```

> logger/index.js

```
const buildDevLogger = require('./dev-logger');
const buildProdLogger = require('./prod-logger');

let logger = null;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
    logger = buildDevLogger
} else {
    logger = buildProdLogger
}

module.exports = logger();
```

> index.js (this is my main function)

```
const logger = require('./logger');

logger.info('text info');
logger.warn('text warn');
logger.error('text error');
```

Comment: You forgot to call `buildProdLogger`

Comment: sorry, I can't follow you. Could you be a little bit more precise? Also, the native libraby works as expected, but somehow inside the winston-mongodb package there's an endless loop inside.

Comment: `buildProdLogger` is a function. Call it. `logger = buildProdLogger();`

Comment: I am getting an error. ReferenceError: buildProdLogger is not defined

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine wrong. depending on whether this is a production or dev environment, either `buildProdLogger` or `buildDevLogger` is assigned to `logger`  and then `logger()` is called in the next line ...

Comment: @derpirscher You might want to see the edit history of the OP.

Comment: @smartini The code I’m seeing doesn’t seem to produce ReferenceError. Have you included latest changes?

Comment: unfortunatelly I still receive the error message. The edits I performed had nothing to do with the actual problem because the env variable wasn't set to "development". So buildProdLogger has alwaxs been called since initial post.

Comment: I researched a bit and thought that winston-mongodb itself is somehow using a mongodb-lib. I thought maybe users face the same issue with a normal mongoDB lib and found this here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221782/node-script-doesnt-ever-end Could that be the problem? if yes, where could/should I implement the solution in my code? should I use it in my individual code or should I put it somewhere in the winston-mongodb modules (I guess not)?